# Flutter Bind Json data in ListView not showing in UI

Tags: json, api, flutter, dart, rest

My Json response status code is 200 and the object is also created but when I try to bind it with UI in ListView it doesn't show anything. I have also parsed created the model from the json data.

Here's my API_manager.dart file:

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:aritic/models/contactsModel.dart';

// ignore: camel_case_types
class API_Manager {
  Future<ContactsModel> getContacts() async {
    var client = http.Client();
    var contactsModel;
    String contacts_url =
        'https://exampleapi.com';
    String basicAuth = 'Basic auth key example';
    try {
      var response = await client.get(contacts_url,
          headers: <String, String>{'authorization': basicAuth});
      print(response.statusCode);
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        var jsonString = response.body;
        var jsonMap = json.decode(jsonString);
        contactsModel = contactsModel.fromJson(jsonMap);
      }
    } catch (Exception) {
      return contactsModel;
    }
    return contactsModel;
  }
}
```

My UI code:

```
import 'package:aritic/models/contactsModel.dart';
import 'package:aritic/services/api_manager.dart';

class ContactsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ContactsPageState createState() => _ContactsPageState();
}

class _ContactsPageState extends State<ContactsPage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  Future<ContactsModel> _contactsModel;
  bool isSearching = false;
  TabController _tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState

    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(length: 2, initialIndex: 0, vsync: this);
    _tabController.addListener(_handleTabIndex);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _tabController.removeListener(_handleTabIndex);
    _tabController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _handleTabIndex() {
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _contactsModel = API_Manager().getContacts();
    return DefaultTabController(
        length: 2,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Contacts'),
            bottom: PreferredSize(
                child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                  child: TabBar(
                    controller: _tabController,
                    isScrollable: true,
                    unselectedLabelColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.3),
                    indicatorColor: Colors.white,
                    tabs: [
                      Tab(
                        child: Text('Contacts'),
                      ),
                      Tab(
                        child: Text('Companies'),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(40.0)),
            actions: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 16.0),
                child: IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.search),
                  color: Colors.white,
                  onPressed: () {},
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          body: TabBarView(controller: _tabController, children: <Widget>[
            Container(
                height: double.infinity,
                child: FutureBuilder<ContactsModel>(
                    future: _contactsModel,
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      if (snapshot.hasData) {
                        return ListView.builder(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(6),
                            itemCount: snapshot.data.contacts.length,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                              var contact = snapshot.data.contacts[index];
                              return Container(
                                height: 100,
                                color: Colors.white,
                                child: Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Text(contact.owner.username,
                                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16))
                                  ],
                                ),
                              );
                            });
                      } else
                        return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                    })),
            Container(
                height: double.infinity,
                child: ListView(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(6),
                  children: <Widget>[
                    InkWell(
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.push(context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => ViewCompany()));
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        height: 50,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Text(
                              'Example company',
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                            ),
                            Text(
                              'Example company',
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 5,
                    ),
                    InkWell(
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.push(context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => ViewCompany()));
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        height: 50,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Text(
                              'example',
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                            ),
                            Text(
                              'example',
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                )),
          ]),
          floatingActionButton: _bottomButtons(),
        ));
  }

  Widget _bottomButtons() {
    return _tabController.index == 0
        ? FloatingActionButton(
            shape: StadiumBorder(),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) {
                return AddContacts();
              }));
            },
            backgroundColor: Colors.cyan,
            child: Icon(
              Icons.person_add,
              color: Colors.white,
            ))
        : FloatingActionButton(
            shape: StadiumBorder(),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) {
                return AddCompany();
              }));
            },
            backgroundColor: Colors.cyan,
            child: Icon(
              Icons.add,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          );
  }
}
```

Output Screen:
[ListView should be displayed here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWkRp.png)

Dart DevTools network analysis:
[response code is displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2EEiE.png)

Json Viewer:
[Contacts Json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G0ixz.png)

Json sample(complete json too big to upload here):

```
{
    "total": "187144",
    "contacts": {
        "897": {
            "isPublished": true,
        "id": 897,
            "fields": {
                "core": {
                    "points": {
                        "id": "47",
                        "label": "Points"
                    },
                    "firstname": {
                        "id": "2",
                        "label": "First Name",
                        "value": "Jason"
                    },
                    "lastname": {
                        "id": "3",
                        "label": "Last Name",
                        "value": "Lamuda"
                    },
                    "...": {
                             "..." : "..."
                            }
                },
            "ipAddresses": [
                {
                    "ip": "70.127.91.131",
                    "ipDetails": {
                        "city": "Bradenton",
                        "region": "Florida",
                        "timezone": "America/New_York",
                    }
                },
                 "...": {
                             "..." : "..."
                            }
```

Comment: I have tested with the code you provided, and a dummy ContactsModel, and it works OK, so I wonder if the problem is in ContactsModel - please add the code, and an example JSON string.

Comment: verify if your snapshot.data.contacts is not empty.

Comment: log your returned contactsModel.contacts and make sure  it's not empty array. if it is and empty array, please capture your flutter log after request is done and show it to us

Comment: @PatrickO'Hara I've updated the question with sample json viewer, ContactsModel file is too big to upload here. I've tried everything else but had no luck. Can you still help me out?

Comment: @Taur Its not empty, has 2 contacts. I have edited the question with a screenshot of the json viewer. Also the contactsModel I created was from the logged json response that I received through quicktype.io

Comment: @ShreyasBhardwaj I am sorry, but having an image of the JSON is not useful, I need the text.

Comment: @PatrickO'Hara I have edited the question with my Json sample data can you please have a look?

Comment: OK, I found the problem, see my answer below. I did not know about `quicktype.io`, so thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON has this:

```
{
    "total": "187144",
    "contacts": {
        "897": {
            "isPublished": true,
            "id": 897,
            "fields": {
```

So your `ContactModel.contacts` is a `Map` keyed by the id values "897" etc, not a `List`, so this line returns `null`:

```
  var contact = snapshot.data.contacts[index];
```

(This should throw an exception when you reference the members of `contact`.) You can index into the Map like this:

```
List keys = snapshot.data.contacts.keys.toList();
List values = snapshot.data.contacts.values.toList();
return ListView.builder(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(6),
    itemCount: snapshot.data.contacts.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      var contact = values[index];
```

BTW this line in API_Manager is strange:

```
contactsModel = contactsModel.fromJson(jsonMap);
```

It gives a Null pointer exception. It should of course be:

```
contactsModel = ContactsModel.fromJson(jsonMap);
```